# Getting 405 response on OData API Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cors, odata

Currently the Get() request is working as expected but Post() is giving me 405 response. I am using .NET 7.0 with OData 8. This is running on localhost no CORS but added the permissive CORS policy anyway but it is still giving me 405 response. What am I missing here?

Here is the OData Controller:

```
namespace WFM.Server.Controllers.OData
{
    public class PropertiesController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly PropertyService _repo;

        public PropertiesController(PropertyService repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Property>> Get()
        {
            return Ok(_repo.GetQueryableCollection());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [EnableQuery]
        [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
        public IActionResult Post<Property>([FromBody] Property prop)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            return Created(prop);
        }
    }    
}
```

The Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
    builder.EntitySet<WorkTask>("Tasks");
    builder.EntitySet<Property>("Properties");
    builder.EntitySet<WorkOrder>("WorkOrders");
    builder.EntitySet<Contractor>("Contractors");
    builder.EntitySet<Material>("Materials");
    builder.EntitySet<TestDTO>("dtos");
    
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
builder.Services.AddControllers(opt => opt.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true)
    .AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()) .Filter().Select().Expand().OrderBy().SetMaxTop(null).Count())
    .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
        opt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.Configure<DbSettings>(
builder.Configuration.GetSection("fmdb"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DbSettings>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MongoService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<TaskService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PropertyService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WorkOrderService>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .WithMethods("OPTION", "POST");
        });
});
//builder.Services.AddCors();
builder.WebHost.UseUrls(new string[] { "http://*:5262" });
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()){
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

[image: Test from client sending to odata/properties via PostJsonAsAscnc()]

Comment: Could you please share, where did you hosted this app? Have you checked the application log details? Do you have `WebDAV` installed within your hosted server?

Comment: In addition, does, you server only allow https? Then make sure you are sending request from https. As per your program.cs configuration it suppose to accept only https, so make sure your sending endpoint is https.

Comment: Have you tried by removing this `[EnableCors("AllowAll")]` because you don't need to keep it on top of controller if you have written in program.cs.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I have set the service to run on http only. The EnableCors was added after nothing works just throwing it in there. The thing is if I use POST on normal Web API Controller it will work but when using OData controller I get 405.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron This is just running of Visual Studio 2022.I don't have WebDAV installed